# Cannot start a ngnix

Tags: nginx

My developer has added third-party authentications like Google, Twitter to our website. I would like to take over the development now. The first thing I need to do is to be able to test these third-party authentications in localhost. He gave me the following configuration file.

```
upstream mywebsite {
   server 178.62.00.00:443;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/localhost/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/localhost/localhost.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "";
    proxy_ssl_name "www.mywebsite.io";
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;

    location ~ /socialLoginSuccess {
        rewrite ^ '/#/socialLoginSuccess' redirect;
    }

    location ~ /auth/(.*) {
        proxy_pass  https://mywebsite/myapp/auth/$1?$query_string;
        proxy_set_header Host localhost;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding     "";
        proxy_set_header    Proxy               "";
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:3000/;

        # These three lines added as per https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942 to remove socketio error
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

I then put it as `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` under my MacOS. However, I could not run nginx successfully:

```
$ nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

$ brew services start nginx
==> Successfully started `nginx` (label: homebrew.mxcl.nginx)

$ brew services list
Warning: Calling bottle :unneeded is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the stripe/stripe-cli tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/stripe/homebrew-stripe-cli/stripe.rb:9

256
Name                  Status  User     Plist
mongodb-community@3.2 stopped          
nginx                 error   softtimur /usr/local/opt/nginx/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Edit 1:**

I tried to use the [default configuration of nginx](https://pastebin.com/raw/aHwcV8qD), but `brew services restart nginx` followed by `brew services list` still showed error.

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766195/nginx-emerg-server-directive-is-not-allowed-here/41766811#41766811) over on SO.

Comment: I tried [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/weqgti9B), `brew services restart nginx` followed by `brew services list` still returned error.

Comment: What is the content of nginx error log? What is the output of `nginx -T`, note the capital `T`?

Comment: `nginx -T` returns `nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate key "/etc/ssl/localhost/localhost.key": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen('/etc/ssl/localhost/localhost.key','r') error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib)
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`. `sudo nginx -T` returns `nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`. Is there anywhere I could see more about the nginx error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `brew services start nginx`, `brew services list`, `brew services stop nginx` are not reliable here.

By contrast, `sudo nginx` (to start nginx) and `sudo nginx -s stop` work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The configuration snippet given by your colleague should reside inside `http` block.

However, when you put that into `nginx.conf` and use that as a nginx configuration, it doesn't work because the `http` level is missing.

nginx often ships with a `nginx.conf` file, which has good defaults, and then `include` inside the `http` section to include other configuration.

You need to check the `nginx.conf` shipped with your nginx install, and see how it includes other config files.

Comment: I tried to use the [default configuration of nginx](https://pastebin.com/raw/aHwcV8qD), but `brew services restart nginx` followed by `brew services list` still showed error.